# Web APi Vs MVC and Serving static files in ASP.net core Web APi

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

We have an ASP.net MVC app, and we are seeking to migrate it to ASP.net CORE due to client needs.
Actually the app is providing REST services that are consumed by an AngularJS client app served by the same ASP.net app, it's little a mess actually. 
What should i opt for, Web API or MVC ? and if I choose Web API, can it serve static files ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In ASP.NET Core, there is no separation between MVC and WebAPI. The latter would just mean that your “API controllers” are returning data directly instead of returning a view. – The choice you are making is for the template, and just decides what base things get added to your project. But you can always add the static files middleware to any project. Btw. if you are looking at Angular, you could also check out the Angular template which also comes with a client-side build setup for Angular using Webpack.

Answer (score 11):

First of all, Web Api and MVC is merge in ASP.NET Core.

To setup a solution which can run static files

1. Enable static files in the Configure method in the Startup.cs class, add:

   ```
   app.UseStaticFiles();
   ```
2. Add the frontend solution (angularjs files, html etc) to the wwwroot folder.
3. Remove the default launchUrl (*Properties/launchSettings.json*) and set it to an empty string which will make the web server to look for the index.html file in the root instead

Comment: Thanks for your complete awnser, the client needed to deploy the app on ubuntu and migration to .Net core seemed to have a high cost, so we opted for Mono.